# How to restrict user access mobile data when mobile is connected to laptop?

Tags: mobile, audit

When a user connects his mobile phone to a laptop in our organisation, his complete mobile data can be accessed from laptop. How do we control this and restrict the user from accessing mobile data when the phone is connected to laptop by USB?

Comment: Do you mean the information stored on the phone? Is this android, iOS, something else?

Comment: It can be any mobile device.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you mean data tethering from the phone to the laptop.

If it is pure USB, you can force an USB blocking policy via GPO. Blocking WiFi tethering will be much more difficult, unless you restrict the laptopts to certain WiFi points only. The second option will not make you popular, but it will prevent the user from accessing information over a mobile network

**Instructions on Group Policies**

USB tethering is managed over the MTP, which on Windows is the same as a WDP Device.

1. Open the **Group Policy Editor**
2. Go to either **computer** or **user** settings.
3. Administrative Templates \ System \ Removable Storage Access
4. WDP Devices, then disable Read and Write access.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I mean data tethering from the phone to the laptop. Do you have steps how to force an USB blocking policy via GPO.

Comment: @MaazBaig I'll update the post

Answer (score -2):

You can use a DLP solution from a provider as Mcafee, Eset or even Microsoft inTune to prevent data leakage, web filtering and App control.  Be prepared your wallet.. ;)

Comment: Hi we already have a DLP from Mcafee on the endpoints but that doesn't restrict mobile phones to be tethered . Can you help me how do I enforce it.